# Behavior of the pointwise norm of the gradient w.r.t. to boundary conditions in elliptic PDEs

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be some open ball in the interior of a (nice) domain $\Omega$ and $y_i\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ for $i=1,2$.

If I know that
\begin{align}
&\bullet\quad -\Delta y_i=1 \text{ for } i=1,2 \text{ on } B\\
&\bullet\quad 0\leq y_1(x)\leq y_2(x) \text{ on } \bar{B}\\
\end{align}
Does it mean there is a $x\in \bar{B}$ such that $|\nabla y_1(x)|\leq |\nabla y_2(x)|$?

The usual gradient estimates from Gilbard-Trudinger do not seem to help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this.

The idea is that you let $y_2$ be as flat as possible, with large boundary values (so $y_2 = \frac{x^2}{2n} + M$ for some large $M > 0$).

Then you let $y_1 = \frac{x^2}{2n} + B \cdot x + C$ for a very large value of $B$ and corresponding $C$, so that the term in the gradient from $B$ overwhelms the one from the quadratic term. This is not so large $y_1$ is ever allowed to be greater than $M$ - since you can make $M$ as large as you like, this works.

Comment: I would like to know if the first two hypothesis already contradict the third one, in general. In 1D, I believe the first two and the third one are incompatible. Perhaps I should rephrase the original question.

Comment: ah, never mind. You asked a very different question from the one I answered.

Comment: I rephrased it, I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Also, the problem was set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, your example was not and your $y_2$ does not belong to any $H_0^1(a,b)$. I re-apologize for the phrasing.

Comment: Oh, no problem. Hmm. $H^1_0(\Omega)$, not $B$, correct? Are there any conditions on the functions outside $B$?

Comment: Yes, $H_0^1(\Omega)$ but I was referring to the 1D example above. No, not other assumptions besides $y_i\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$, for $i=1,2$.

Comment: Then what's wrong with just multiplying the functions I suggested by some compactly supported function to make them 0 a bit outside the unit interval?

Comment: @RayYang Your answer indeed resolves the question in the negative, i.e., there need not be such $x$. But it looks odd that the first sentence is "I think you should be able to do this", as if the OP's conjecture was true. Please consider rephrasing.